# Blender Suggestions

Tags: units

Where exactly can I discuss/suggest ideas/areas where improvement could be made? The problem I am having is finding a place among all the various sites where I can actually submit a suggestion. Can anybody give me an address or email anything that will let me make my suggestion?

I am not a coder and all the places seem to revolve around being a contributor, where do users put in improvement ideas?

I worked in engineering for many years and the biggest problem I have is trying to work to scale in blender (used Solidworks), there are some simple things that could be done to make this very powerful.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about using Blender

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos but it around blender, it is actually on-topic.

Answer (score 7):

The best place were you can put your sugestions is [rightclickselect](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/) site.